# Changing color of bars in different bar charts within same application

Tags: android, achartengine

I have 3 buttons displaying 3 different bar charts in the same application. when i click any of the button it displays bar chart with same color as shown by others. Now i want to display these 3 bar charts in 3 different colors. How is it possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XYSeriesRenderer.setColor` function and set it to a different colour for each `Barchart`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will have to have each bar added to a separate series.